# Android App Progress Bar Won't Update When Using Thread and AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, progress-bar

I have an android app with a class, **WifiAudioActivity** that extends the Activity class.

In a nutshell, when a button on the app is pressed, a method is run, which uses a progress bar to show the progress of the method.

I show the progress bar and update it using **AsyncTasks**.

The problem is, in order to get the progress of the method, I have it running on another thread, so a while loop on the **AsyncTask** thread can constantly as for an updated progress value and display it in the progress bar. However, when I call **progessUpdate()**, which updates the progress bar, **after** I set the method on the thread running, it doesn't update the progress bar, it doesn't even jump to the **onProgressUpdate()** method code.

Interestingly, I can update the progress with dummy values before I run the Thread with the method on.

I presume it is a problem with my threads - can anyone help?

```
private ProgressDialog downloadAllDialog;
private ProgressDialog usingDialog;

private int totalDownloadSize;

private Download downloadAll;

private int totalBlocksLeft;

private boolean downloadComplete;
private boolean downloadFailed;

public void downloadAllClick(View view)     //When the download all button is clicked
{
    new PerformTask().execute();
}

private class PerformTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Integer> 
{
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        showDialog();
    }

    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... voi) 
    {
        int retryCount = 0;

        downloadComplete = false;   //Assume the download is not complete
        downloadFailed = false;

        totalBlocksLeft = 0;

        progressUpdater.run();       //Running method thread

        publishProgress(20);     //THIS DOES NOT WORK

        while ((retryCount < Consts.RETRY_TOTAL) && (!(downloadComplete)))
        {
            int blocksDownloaded = 0;

            while ((downloadComplete == false) && (downloadFailed == false))   
            {
                 blocksDownloaded = totalDownloadSize - downloadAll.getTotalBlocksLeft();    //GOT FROM THE RUNNING THREAD METHOD

                 publishProgress(blocksDownloaded);   //DOES NOT WORK
            }  

            ...
        }

        return totalBlocksLeft ;
    }

    Thread progressUpdater = new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            downloadComplete = downloadAll.downloadAudio(totalBlocksLeft);  //Download the audio

            if (!(downloadComplete))
            {
                downloadFailed = true;
            }
        }
    };

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) 
    {
        usingDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) 
    {
        removeDialog();
    }
}

protected Dialog onCreateDialog() 
{   
    downloadAllDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

    downloadAllDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);

    downloadAllDialog.setMax(totalDownloadSize);

    downloadAllDialog.setProgress(0);

    downloadAllDialog.setMessage("Download All");

    usingDialog = downloadAllDialog;

return downloadAllDialog;
}
```

}

As it stands, in the key bit of code:

```
blocksDownloaded = totalDownloadSize - downloadAll.getTotalBlocksLeft();    //GOT FROM THE RUNNING THREAD METHOD

publishProgress(blocksDownloaded);   //DOES NOT WORK
```

blocksDownloaded, which gets its updated value from the thread running method, is updating with the progress. I'm sure it's not technically right, but having the thread in the AsyncTask does actually run the method whilst getting the progress update in the main method. It is therefore only the updating of the progress bar that doesn't work.

Comment: You do not need a thread at all, your approach is wrong, first of all you are doing runOnUIThread in doInBackground of AsyncTask which is wrong, you are supposed to do only the UI related stuff in runOnUIThread. Then you do not need progressUpdater thread as AsyncTask itself is an optimal thread. Try refactoring and make the code readable so someone can help you.

Comment: As you will note, what you have told me to fix, is exactly my question - I do not know what to do. The getTotalBlocks() method will not get the new value if the method does not run on a separate thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are not using AsyncTask properly. You seem to be calling the download code on the UI thread, which is probably blocking the progressBar from updating.

I can suggest the following. This will make sure you are using AsyncTask properly. When you use AsyncTask properly the code should get a lot simplified as well.

1. Do not create any threads and do not use the runOnUIThread method. The AsyncTask provides you the callback methods which run on appropriate threads.
2. The main download code should be in doInBackground method.
3. You should call publishProgress at some points somewhere inside the download code.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but it isn't really feasable to put the download code in the doInBackground Method as it is spread over 4 classes, being an absolutely massive method. 

I've removed the runOnUIThread, but I still can't work out how to both download and update the progress bar at the same time.

Comment: if you are looking to run the download on a separate thread, you should call progressUpdater.start() instead of progressUpdater.run()

Comment: Thank you so much! Not entirely sure why, but that's fixed it!!

Comment: Well, calling the run method did not start a new thread at all. The download was running on the AsyncTask background thread. So the publishProgress would not have been called until the download was complete.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call

```
progressUpdater.start();
```

instead of

```
progressUpdater.run();
```